# Reference request for Poincare-Hopf theorem in a compact submanifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

I recently read the [following question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52023/is-there-a-poincare-hopf-index-theorem-for-non-compact-manifolds) about the Poincare-Hopf theorem in a compact submanifold. All the answers were very satisfactory to me. Is there any reference where I can look for more details of the proof given on the first answer?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on what you would like details on?  This argument about adapting vector fields to triangulations is a standard one.  You can likely find it in a few differential topology textbooks, for example I think Guillemin and Pollack has a version of this kind of argument.

Comment: I am trying to understand how one can adapt the Poincare-Hopf index theorem to a non-compact manifold. In particular, I am considering a vector field that does not vanish at the infinity of my non-compact manifold. The [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52023/is-there-a-poincare-hopf-index-theorem-for-non-compact-manifolds) of Professor Bill Thurston is exactly what I am looking for. I would like to read a reference to improve my knowledge (I am self studying the Poincare-Hopf theorem and this topic is new to me).

Comment: For non-compact manifolds you have the problem that the Euler characteristic may not be defined.  Are you restricting to some class of manifolds where it is defined?

Comment: The manifold is the infinity cylinder $M=S^1\times \mathbb{R}$. I have a vector field $V$ defined all over $M$. I know, from the context of my problem, that this vector field _does not_ have isolated zeroes for high values of height $H$. I want to compute some topological invariant related to the zeros of $V$.

Comment: I was wondering if I can choose a compact submanifold $N, \partial N \subset M$ where V does not vanish on the boundary $\partial N$. Then I would compute the Poincare-Hopf theorem for the submanifold $N, \partial N$. Since I know the behavior of the vector field at infinity, it would be sufficient for me to know the index of $V$ in a compact region $S^1\times[-H, H]$ where H is a larger number.

Comment: So are you saying the zeros have cluster points in $S^1 \times [-H,H]$ for some finite value of $H$?

Comment: Apparently my last comment was redirected to the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139021/discussion-between-ninpou-and-ryan-budney)